# fwrite writes more bytes than it's told

Tags: visual-c++, fwrite

I'm writing an **unsigned char** buffer to file (C++):

```
FILE* f = fopen("out.data","wb");
size_t count = fwrite((const void *)pBuf, sizeof(unsigned char), dl, f);
```

When I read it, I get more bytes than the **'dl'** I expect to get. Anyone knows why ?
There was a similar question where the cause was 'fopen(...,"w")' instead of 'fopen(...,"wb")'.

I read the file using Matlab (tried both 'r' and 'rb' in Matlab's fopen), if it has something to do with it ...

Thanks !

Comment: Can you do a hexdump on the file ?

Comment: can you post file reading code ?

Comment: what is added incorrectly to the file?

Comment: Please show the read code as kannan asked. How many bytes are you writing, how many get read, and what does the the file system say the file size is (`dir` command)? Some troubleshooting tips: if you look at the data after reading it, are there added CR (0x0d) characters?  If you compare the write buffer with the read buffer (as hex dumps or whatever), where do things first look different?